# How to merge neighboring bounding boxes

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I would like to join nearby bounding boxes, right now I am able to detected bounding boxes for each word.

Currently code is giving bounding box for each letter, how do I modify so that it will give one bounding box depends on tolerance

```
rect_box = []
im = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(1,31))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 15) # dilate
contours0,_ = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # get contours
contours = [cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 50, True) for cnt in contours0]
(contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
for contour in contours:
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if h>100 and w>100:
        continue

    if h<10 or w<10:
        continue
    pad_w, pad_h = int(0.05*w), int(0.15*h)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x-pad_w,y-pad_h),(x+w+pad_w,y+h+pad_h),(255,0,255),1,shift=0)
    rect_box.append(((x-pad_w,y-pad_h),(x+w+pad_w,y+h+pad_h)))

cv2.imwrite("rectangle.png", im)
cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# For joining words 
out = []
prev = rect_box[0]
temp_list = [rect_box[0][0]]

for num in rect_box[0:]:
    if num[0]-10 > prev[0]:
        out += [temp_list]
        temp_list = [num[0]]
    else:
        temp_list.append(num)
    prev = num
out.append(temp_list)

for i in out:
    i.pop(0)
out_1 = [x for x in out if x != []]

out_2 = []
for i in out_1:
    min_v = list(map(min, zip(*i)))
    max_v = list(map(max, zip(*i)))
    out_2.append((min_v[0], min_v[1], max_v[2],max_v[3]))

for i in out_2:
    x,y,w,h = i
    print(x,y,w,h)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(w,y+h),(255,0,255),1,shift=0)


def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
        key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)
```

Input:[image: Input image]
Output: [image: Output image]
After appending co-ordinates, I grouped them on the bases of y axis, and took min, max. This gave me bounding box for lines, same thing I did for whole region using x axis. But, somehow it is not working the way I want.

Comment: Can you post all the code? The `sort_contours()` function is missing.

Comment: @stephen please check

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use case for `cv2.dilate()`. Whenever you need to combine multiple individual contours into a single contour, you can dilate. To determine the tolerance, you can adjust the [structuring type](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element), the kernel size, or the number of dilate iterations

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,2))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

dilate_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(opening, dilate_kernel, iterations=4)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: It will vary image to image right, I have to adjust parameters according to image.

Comment: If your desired ROIs are in the same general area, you might not need to change the parameters. But generally in image processing, the parameters will change according to the image

Comment: Ok, So what is the other way to find ROI as complete box rather than line or word?

Comment: I used co-ordinates to join line and area. but somehow it is not giving me good result.

Comment: You can dilate to find the ROI as a single contour